# What PL/pgSQL debugger can I use?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, mac-os-x, debugging

I'm building a lot of PL/pgSQL functions and a debugger would really come in handy because `RAISE NOTICE` is not enough.

I read about a pgAdmin plugin you can install but it was only on Windows and I'm running Mac OS X.

Comment: I was under the strong impression the plpgsql debugger was portable. It's here: http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pldebugger.git;a=summary

Comment: I guess I would need to recompile PostgreSQL in order to use pldebugger. Do you know any other way? Recompiling the dbms is something I want to avoid.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Pretty sure it's just an extension. Compile the extension and install it.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, unless I did something wrong. I unzipped it and the README said to put the files in `/contrib` in the root folder of PostgreSQL (which didn't have it) and when I ran `make` I had an error because the `/src` folder wasn't found clearly because it wasn't there.

Comment: Huh... try `make USE_PGXS=1` . If that doesn't work it might need a Makefile fix.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an article I wrote for how to get one installed on Ubuntu.

[Installation instructions for the pldebugger for PostgreSQL](http://kirk.webfinish.com/?p=277)

```
pg_config --version
"9.3beta2"
```

Look here for source code matching your version of PostgreSQL:
ftp://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/

For me, it was:

```
wget ftp://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v9.3beta2/postgresql-9.3beta2.tar.bz2
tar xvjf postgresql-9.3beta2.tar.bz2
cd postgresql
USE_PGXS=1 ./configure
USE_PGXS=1 make
cd contrib
git clone git://git.postgresql.org/git/pldebugger.git
make
cd pldebugger
USE_PGXS=1 make
sudo USE_PGXS=1 make install
```

These instructions assume that you have the development packages for your version of PostgreSQL already installed on your system.